# How to space radioButtons

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am fairly new to Java and am working on a `QuizFrame` project as a means to get better with FX. The code is still a work in progress, but my main question is: How does one space the radio buttons?

When I was doing in Swing it seemed like the buttons automatically spaced themselves, but here it is just one radio button with all the options stacked on top of each other.

Here is the code:

```java
public class QuizFrame2 extends Application {

    RadioButton[] optionButtons;
    TextArea questionArea;
    Button submitButton;
    Question[] questions;
    int currQuestion;
    Pane questionPanel;
    String[] choices;
    TextArea resultArea;
    
    final int NUM_OPTIONS = 4;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setVgap(5);
        grid.setHgap(5);
        
        questions = new Question[2];
        questions[0] = new Question();
        questions[1] = new Question("What is 1+1?", 
           new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"}, "2");
        
        currQuestion = 0;
        
        questionArea = new TextArea();
        questionArea.setText(questions[currQuestion].getQuestion());
        submitButton = new Button();
        submitButton.setText("Submit");
        
        questionArea.setPrefSize(500, 50);
        
        ToggleGroup bG = new ToggleGroup();
        
        RadioButton[] optionsButton = new RadioButton[NUM_OPTIONS];
        questionPanel = new Pane();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < optionsButton.length; i++)
        {

         optionsButton[i] = new RadioButton(questions[currQuestion].getOption(i));
         optionsButton[i].setToggleGroup(bG);
         questionPanel.getChildren().add(optionsButton[i]);
        }
        
        submitButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        
                    }
                });

        GridPane.setConstraints(submitButton, 0, 80);
        GridPane.setConstraints(questionArea, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(questionPanel, 0, 3);
        
        grid.getChildren().add(questionPanel);
        grid.getChildren().add(questionArea);
        grid.getChildren().add(submitButton);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("TextArea Input");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to answer your question without knowing how you want the buttons laid out. Unlike Swing, where you have a generic panel with a layout manager attached, JavaFX has no separate layout manager class: you simply use one or more appropriate `Pane` subclass(es) depending on the layout you want. See the [layout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) for a rundown of built-in layout panes.

Comment: I see. The layout is also a simple one with the textArea on top, the options (aka radio buttons) in the center, and the submit button at the bottom.

Comment: Yes, but you need to put the radio buttons in a specific layout pane. Right now you just have them in a generic `Pane` (`questionPanel`), which does no layout.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I read through the layout tutorial and it seems like he/she made a class for each hbox/vbox?

Comment: If I understood correctly, do you mean that the questionPanel should be specified as to what kind of Pane as in GridPane or FlowPane?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Use a specific (predefined) `Pane` subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the `RadioButton`s in a generic `Pane`, which does no layout. You need to use a specific `Pane` subclass that does the layout you need.

For example, you could use a [`VBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html):

```
questionPanel = new VBox();

for(int i = 0; i < optionsButton.length; i++)
{

 optionsButton[i] = new RadioButton(questions[currQuestion].getOption(i));
 optionsButton[i].setToggleGroup(bG);
 questionPanel.getChildren().add(optionsButton[i]);


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so the questionPanel itself had to be a specific pane? Because what I was attempting to do is keep it as Pane or GridPane and try to insert it into a VBox. As in, vbox.getChildren().add(questionPanel) in hopes that its row based nature would split them.